# Add extra trigger to @Schedule

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have an EJB with the following scheduled method:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
public void runWorkerManager() {
    final boolean jobProcessed = this.workerManager.execute();
    if (jobProcessed) {
        this.runWorkerManager();
    }
}
```

The idea is that there often is a second (and third and so on) job to process after one is processed, so I would like to run the `execute()` method again like above.

The problem is that doing it in this way is really bad, since I don't release the `EJB` thread. Instead I would like to add an extra trigger to the `@Schedule` that runs the entire `runWorkerManager()` again as soon as possible. I have however not found a way to do this.
Is this possible? If it is not, is there another way to get a similar behaviour?

Comment: have you consider to create a new [managed](https://concurrency-ee-spec.java.net/javadoc/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was first getting a reference to the `TimerService` like this:

```
@Resource
TimerService timerService;
```

Then I just added a `@Timeout` annotation to my method, and used the [`TimerService#createTimer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html#createTimer%28long,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method to add a new trigger:

```
@Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
@Timeout
public void runWorkerManager() {
    final boolean jobProcessed = this.workerManager.execute();
    if (jobProcessed) {
        timerService.createTimer(10L, "Check for more jobs...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this use case calls for `MessageDrivenBean`.

In your case I'd make `WorkerManager` a `MessageDrivenBean` listening on some `JMS queue` to which `jobs` are being sent. This way you ensure that whenever the job arrives it will be processed as soon as possible.

Comment: This seems like a total overhaul of the structure of the program, which isn't really something I want to do.

Comment: You already are using EJB so I assumed it would be much of a trouble. Anyway, I don't know any way in which you can achieve something similar using only Stateless beans. Maybe you could try some inversion of control and let your job storage notify workerManagers that some jobs are ready to be executed?